# Is this a valid way of horizontally centering absolute-positioned elements?

Tags: css, positioning, css-position, centering

I want a reusable method to horizontally centre absolute-positioned fixed-width elements within their containers, and I want reusable code (e.g., no negative pixel margins).

I've stumbled across a combination that works perfectly:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronadams/Mquha/

```html
<div class="outer center">
    <div class="inner center"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px; height: 400px;
    background: #999;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; height: 400px;
    background: #666;
}

.center {
    left: 0; right: 0;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
```

It's clean, it's (relatively) easily understood, it appears to work in IE 8+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari… but it also appears to be an enormous, dirty, no-good positioning hack, one that could come apart at the seams at any time.

I can't find any documentation to suggest whether this positioning behaviour is correct or incorrect. Which is it? Appropriate for production, or completely unreliable?

Comment: Oh my god!! it also works for vertical centering!! o_O

Comment: Seems good as far as you're not looking for **fluid layout**.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from using relative positioning + negative margins (other than the fact that this looks like more code).  Either way, you have to know the element's size.  Since you already know its size, dividing it by 2 seems like a non-issue.

Comment: @cimmanon In this method, the margins are automatically calculated by the rendering engine. This is more robust than calculating them manually, which introduces more places where a mistake can be made.

Comment: @SonuJoshi Actually, it works great with fluid layouts, too: http://jsfiddle.net/aaronadams/N8nWr/

Comment: @laconbass Huh, you're right! http://jsfiddle.net/aaronadams/rkD7h/ And thanks to Marc Audet's answer below, I actually know where to look for documentation, and sure enough, that's also a documented behaviour: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height Great find.

Comment: @cimmanon this methods needs to set the dimensions, but the values of them are not neccesary to the "centering code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the constraint that your two containers `.outer` and `.inner` are absolutely positioned, then what you have done is not only correct, but, it is also the only way to do it
when the parent container's width is not specified.

Your solution works exactly according to the CSS 2.1 specification, it is robust.

For reference, you need to review:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width

which specifies how the width of an absolutely positioned element is computed.

In your jsFiddle example, you need to realize that the containing block for the two `<div>`'s is the viewport or the root element.  You have yet to say anything about the vertical placement by specifying the `top` or `bottom` properties.  Also, since the absolutely positioned elements are out-of-flow, their intrinsic height does not factor into computing the height of the containing block, and in some applications, this is a factor that would make this approach unusable without modifications.

In addition, if you were to wrap your sample code in a relatively positioned wrapper `<div>`, and you applied a fixed width, then the child elements would still center correctly, as shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/aNS5j/ (Keep in mind that you may need to allow sufficient height in the wrapper element.)

However, as pointed out earlier in a comment, if the width of the containing block (either the viewport or the wrapper element in my demo) is less than the width of your child elements (400px in your example), then the centering would no longer work, **BUT** this would still be the correct behavior according to the CSS specification.

Your question has touched upon a basic but important fundamental of how the CSS visual formatting model works.

**Aside**

You could still get the same effect without using absolute positioning on the `.inner` element, in which case, `margin: 0 auto` would have been sufficient.  The cost savings in a slightly more concise CSS declaration.

**About Negative Margins**

Although negative margins do work and are implemented consistently across most modern browsers, the CSS 2.1 specification does not say how negative margins should be implemented.  In theory, negative margins could break down in some user agents that still conform to the CSS specification.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for: documentation of the behaviour. I wasn't able to find it myself (those official W3C documents are a bit overwhelming for me). Obviously this still needs to be tested across a large number of browsers, but in the world I live in, it could prove to be a monumental time- and line-saver.

Comment: @AaronAdams Glad to help, this was a good question since it invoked quite a few insightful comments. The W3C docs are tough to read, as if they were written by both mathematicians and lawyers, but they have led to standards compliant browsers, which has allowed our industry to develop in a rational way.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

I've alway's found that once you're dipping into the `position:absolute;` pool, you're abandoning an elegant solution. Regretfully, there are a lot of cases where absolute positioning is the only way to solve a problem.

As far as I know the industry standard is using negative margin, as you mentioned:  http://jsfiddle.net/Mquha/3/

And again, this feels dirty and moreover: not reusable.

I've looked into the approach you suggested, and your way seems like a fairly modern discovery, and I'm a bit surprised that it even works. At any rate, it is a lot easier than the negative margin method and seems to be supported by all major browsers, like you say. 
I'm adopting the method you proposed in the future, still not perfect but at least it's less dirty than using negative margins. I can only advise you to do the same when you're using absolute positioning.

Comment: Why you think absolute positioning isn't elegant?

Comment: Absolute positioning for centering only works well when the content is predictably smaller than the viewport or surrounding content.

Comment: I personally think it is not elegant because when you use it, most of the time you are breaking the flow of the page. @cimmanon, absolute positioning is almost always predictable in size, hence the name absolute positioning. I would like to know what it is about my answer that merits a down vote.

Answer (score -1):

This is my best bet

change your css to

```
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px; height: 400px;
    background: #999;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; height: 400px;
    background: #666;
}

.center {
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}
```

And your html to

```
<div id="outer center" class="center">
    <div id="inner center" class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: the question's solution actually works, the question is if is desirable for production use or not